# Sample datasets for practice - Oracle pl/sql

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, dataset, sample

I am a new user of SQL, I use Oracle pl/sql as a Programming software. I have done an introductory course to SQL that included some datasets. However I'd like to continue practicing, some real life problems that include requests of querying very simple statements to difficult ones that include indexes, etc.

Does anyone have any links/sites where I can further pursue SQL training for free? I've done a Stakexchange and Google search with not much luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you probably know, Oracle ussually comes with some sample schemas like HR, SH... listed [here](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/COMSC/overview.htm#COMSC00040)
Also, you can install [HammerOra](http://www.hammerdb.com/index.html) benchmarking tool. It's commonly used to test [TPC-C](http://www.tpc.org/tpcc/) and [TPC-H](http://www.tpc.org/tpch/default.asp) on different RDBMS. It will install some schemas on your DB with variable size.
You can also install some [virtual appliances](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/community/developer-vm/index.html).
There are more there, but I think the coolest is [StackOverflow DB](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange), too bad is MSSQL.

Comment: Do they include tasks too?

Comment: @KashifHussain You should probably take a look at Developers Day VM:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/databaseappdev-vm-161299.html. You'll find any videos just looking for Oracle's Developers Day VM: https://community.oracle.com/groups/otn-vts-database-replay-library/overview

Comment: @KashifHussain as a next step, if you install HammerDB you can also go through the documentation an take a look at the queries.
Also, you can try to help your community here at SO!

Comment: @KashifHussain you'll probably want to start with Developers Day VM. Also working with a Virtual Machine you can destroy your DB an just reinstall the VM.

Comment: First, you may or may not know you can download and install Oracle Enterprise Edition. If you use it only for learning and evaluation, it's free. Then, you can try to answer old questions (and even new ones!) here on SO and at OTN - that's what I use for my own practice.